# Is "convert.tobase64string" in .Net equal to "base64_encode" in PHP?

Tags: php, .net

Can any one please let me know, Is `convert.tobase64string` in .Net equal to `base64_encode` in PHP?

Comment: Try it! Shouldn't be too hard to test. But actually I think, that the implementation is the same - but you have to make sure that the strings use the same character encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. They are the same. They all generate the RFC compliant Base64 strings.